# Why is Event.RENDER not being dispatched?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flex3, rendering, stage

I made a class, which has to register to the Event.RENDER event so that it will know when the stage is being rendered. The simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
package
{
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   public final class Test extends Sprite
   {
        public final function Test()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,added,false,0,true);
        }

        private final function added(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("added to stage");
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RENDER, renderHandler,false,0,true);
        }

        private final function renderHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("Event.RENDER dispatched!");
        }
   }
}
```

The Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event is being dispatched. However, the Event.RENDER event is not. Any idea what I may be doing wrong here? The parent is adding this object as a child to the stage, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: are you sure stage.invalidate() is being called after its been added?

Comment: I am not calling stage.invalidate() at all.. should I?

Comment: Yes, see here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/display/Stage.html#invalidate()

Comment: Ya, that one is a little confusing at first. Think of it as JUST_BEFORE_RENDER. If your looking for a general update event, look at ENTER_FRAME

Comment: I am looking for a JUST_BEFORE_RENDER event. However, I do not understand how to use it with the invalidate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the `stage.invalidate()` method to dispatch the `Event.RENDER` event. According to the [AS3 reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#invalidate()), `Event.RENDER` is dispatched just before the screen is rendered, giving all listening objects the chance to update. I've used `Event.RENDER` to redraw static shapes only when something has changed their parameters. It's faster than redrawing every frame.

Comment: Event.RENDER is undependable.  It doesn't fire as frequently as it should when the stage is being resized for example.  If you drag the window corner of the stand-alone Flash Player to resize it, Event.RENDER will NOT be called every frame while the stage is being resized, EVEN THOUGH Event.RESIZE will be dispatched every frame, the resize handler calls stage.invalidate, updates object position, and the player renders them at their new location... but many many Event.RENDER events are missing.  This makes Event.RENDER undependable, and useless.  Can anyone else confirm this behavior?

Comment: This comment would make a good question on its own: "Is Event.RENDER dispatched when the stage resized?" Include your evidence, and see if it's a problem with your code or AS3 itself. Make sure to phrase it as a question, and not as a statement.